# Replace a string with AutoHotkey, advanced?

Tags: replace, autohotkey

I'm having this issue: I program a lot in several programming
languages.

I need to enter a lot of code every day, but I recently was using
NetBeans and when (in Java), you type `sout{TAB}`, it returns
`System.out.println"{this is where the cursor is, so I can begin
typing in here right away}";`

I think this could be done using AutoHotkey, but how?

What I would like to have is a possibility to insert certain commands,
like `echo{TAB}` and it would replace with `echo ("{this is where the
cursor is, so I can begin typing in here right away}");`

If possible, I'd like to be able to tell where the cursor will be and
copy/paste what I would like a command to be replaced with.

Regards, Aart

Comment: Hey Aart! It would help if you copied your answer into the answer box below and answer your own question. It will be easier for others to find later. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, but at that time, I wasn't allowed to by StackOverflow. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! :)

```
:*:echo`t::echo (""); {left 4}
```

If you want to use it in PHP, for example, to type a `while` really fast, use:

```
:*:query`t::$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");{ENTER}while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {{}{ENTER}{ENTER}{}}{left 2}
```

Source: 
[Always look at the readme first... :$](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm)

Answer (score 2):

1. Replace the text as usual.
2. Send CursorLeft a number of times to the end of the block you want selected.
3. Send a ShiftDown.
4. Move the Cursor further to the left to the beginning of the block you want selected.
5. Send a ShiftUp.

Comment: You solution is definitely shorter ;)

Comment: ^_^ Thanks for your help anyway.